# Travis CI - 401 - Build Failing - Bad Credentials on Private Repo

Tags: github, build, travis-ci

Having some trouble with this build, giving me:

```
No stash entries found.
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/octokit-4.6.2/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete': GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)
```

Looked up similar threads, and tried to solve it by
going into github - personal tokens, selecting all scopes, but delete repo, and generating a private key there.

Then Using travis encrypt --pro KEY="secretvalue" (pro, since im using travis.com)
and updating my travis.yml with the output

```
deploy:
  - provider: releases
    api_key:
      secure: KEY_GENERATED_BY_TRAVIS_ECRYPT_PRO
```

Still fails, Anything else I could try to solve this?
Or any place/route I can test my credentials against?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using `travis setup releases --com --force`, that generated a new key on `travis.yml` that solved that problem. Hope it helps someone